# Why do we need to encrypt local persistent data in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

In release build, the default value of `android:debuggable=false`, which make the package not debuggable `run-as: package not debuggable`. Therefore, we cannot access any data in the package. So, my question is if we cannot access the package data, e.i `Room, SharedPreferences`, then why we need to encrypt user credential or sensitive data saved locally for caching purpose? Can we not encrypt them?